# newTrigger AppsScript doesn't appear in the UI

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I ran this apps-script code:

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("foo")
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(36)
      .create();
```

But I see no change in the triggers UI:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### everyMinutes(n): n must be 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30

As it is stated in the offical documentation, [everyMinutes(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn):

> Specifies to run the trigger every n minutes. n **must** be **1, 5, 10, 15**
> or **30**.

You chose `36` which is not supported.

For example, this works:

```
function foo() {
  // code here to be executed every 30 minutes
}

function createTrigger(){
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("foo").timeBased().everyMinutes(30).create();
}
```

Make sure you execute **once** the `createTrigger` function in order to create the trigger for the `foo` function:

[image]

Check also the error message. To my surprise, the error message is quite descriptive:

> Exception: The value you passed to everyMinutes was invalid. It must
> be one of 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30.

Comment: How come I don't see any error message? I don't have any try-catch.

Comment: @EladBenda also make sure to **refresh** the project's trigger page a couple of times to see the created trigger.

Comment: @Marios how you get the dark theme?

Comment: @fullfine thanks for your comment. Install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appsscript-color/ciggahcpieccaejjdpkllokejakhkome?hl=en) extension and it will appear as color option in the script editor ui (with the name Colors in the top menu).